# seekbar inside value

Tags: android

is it possible to get my currentvalue inside that seekbar whenever am moving?how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a textview or edittext and place it next to seekbar.
then on
    SeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener's

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2)
```

method,change the value of edittext
here,

```
txt_SeekBarValue.setText(Integer.toString(arg1));
```

Comment: actually i need that value inside seek button means for example i have small rectangle button, i can move that ,usually i will get value in right side of seekbar i will get that value ,but i want inside that small button i want to get my value